# Visual Studio 2022: What is the Feature recommending style changes?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2022 to 17.4 and noticed the editor starting adding red box highlighting around multiple lines trying to encourage me to change it to a single very long line.

[image]

**What is this feature called and how do I configure it?**

*NOTE:* I'm pretty sure this is coming from Visual Studio - I also run ReSharper, but this doesn't look a ReSharper plugin; there's no signature yellow light bulb.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Intellicode. In Tools:Options:Intellicode:General, try unchecking "C# suggestions". Notice that it is suggesting some real changes, not just a formatting change.

Comment: Is this going to turn off all Suggestions?  Any idea is there's a more granular setting I can turn off?